# Error al reconocer las rutas de una fuente en Angular

Tags: css, angular, scss, fuentes

No me reconoce la ruta local de la fuente, pero lo he comprobado y es correcta. Mi archivo fonts.scss está dentro de la carpeta fonts junto con las fuentes. Adjunto código del archivo. Si pongo una ruta http si la reconoce, es al poner la direccion en local del archivo.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MontserratRegular';
  src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'), url('/src/assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: $fontDefaultRegular;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Quita `src` de la ruta, a ver si funciona

Answer (score 0):

Intenta de está forma:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MontserratRegular';
  src: local('Montserrat Regular'), local('Montserrat-Regular'), 
  url('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: $fontDefaultRegular;
  font-style: normal;
}
```